# Вывод ошибки php с помощью ajax

Tags: ajax, php, json

Здравствуйте! Можно ли как-то вывести ошибку, записанную, допустим, в массив с ошибками (PHP), с помощью ajax?

Видел вариант с json, если можно, объясните поподробнее, что да как, и если есть еще варианты, просьба написать.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в каком месте ошибка должна дожидаться, когда её затребуют по AJAX (если речь идёт о формирующем страницу php-файле, то он к этому времени свою работу должен завершить)

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно делаю простой перебор массива:

```
<?php
$str = ""; //Ответ для JS;
$error_array = array('Ошибка 1', 'Ошибка 2', 'Ошибка Ошибка'); //Исходный массив;
foreach ($error_array as $val)
{
//Во избежание повторения разделителей (если в элементе массива есть запятая, то это приведет к нежелательным последствиям), стоит заменить все запятые на HTML-мнемоники (можно код);
$val = str_replace(",", "&#44", $val);
//Теперь добавляем к строке ответа;
$str .= $val.",";
}
echo($str);
?>
```

В итоге, ajax-скрипт получает такую строку:

"Ошибка 1,Ошибка 2, Ошибка Ошибка"

Осталось только обработать ее:

```
//JavaScript (тело принимающей функции, answer - ответ от сервера (наша строка));
answer = answer.split(',');
```

Все, теперь answer - тот же массив, что был в PHP. Если используете другой разделитель, то можно воспользоваться [такой](http://blog.laptev.info/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/characters-cheat-sheet1.png) табличкой.

Comment: Не уверен в работоспособности при больших объемах информации, но пока нигде не имел проблем.

Comment: Большое спасибо, но, не подскажите, как вывести переменную из php в ajax? Первый день разбираюсь с ним, пока что туго.

Comment: @Indev, [``json_encode()``](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) и [``JSON.parse()``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) уже не в моде?